# vba macro to paste data from multiple sheets one after another

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook that has invoice data for every month with an identical layout. I was wondering if there is a macro that can copy the data from each sheet and paste it all one after the other.

So the first sheet is P1, then P2, P3 etc until P12. I want a macro that will paste P1 data onto a new sheet, then P2 data right underneath it, then P3 etc until the end.

I imagine this would be some sort of For loop, but I'm not sure what the code would look like (I'm very new to vba)

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: What kind of data? A **single cell** or a **single row** or **several rows** ???

Comment: Around 3 rows per sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this option?

```
Sub CopyDataWithoutHeaders()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim shLast As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "RDBMergeSheet" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "RDBMergeSheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    'Fill in the start row
    StartRow = 2

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            'Find the last row with data on the DestSh and sh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)
            shLast = LastRow(sh)

            'If sh is not empty and if the last row >= StartRow copy the CopyRng
            If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then

                'Set the range that you want to copy
                Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))

                'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
                If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                End If

                'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
                'values or want to copy everything look below example 1 on this page
                CopyRng.Copy
                With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With

            End If

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win002.htm

Answer (score 0):

Because details are very limited in order to get an idea of the sheets' structure i try to create general code which with some modifications will satisfy your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim wsTest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim LRW As Long, LRF As Long, LCW As Long

'Here we create a separate sheet namded wsFull to paste the data in it.
Set wsTest = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set wsTest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("wsFull")
On Error GoTo 0

If wsTest Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets.Add.Name = "wsFull"
End If

Set wsTest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("wsFull")

'Here we loop all sheets except the new sheet named wsFull
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "wsFull" Then

        With ws
            'Here we find last column (using first row) & last row (using Column A) for each sheet we loop
            LRW = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            LCW = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        End With

        'Here we find the last row of wsFull in order to find where we will paste the data in.
        LRF = wsTest.Cells(wsTest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            'We paste the data in column A
            If LRF = 1 And wsTest.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
                ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LRW, LCW)).Copy wsTest.Range("A1")
            Else
                ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LRW, LCW)).Copy wsTest.Range("A" & LRF + 1)
            End If

    End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm really confused as to how the worksheet names are updated - like how/where in this code does it say go from worksheet P1 and copy and paste its data into wsfull, then go to P2 and do the same and so on and forth

Comment: I also got an object variable error in line where you define LRF

Comment: I edit the code to correct the error.Also movement from one sheet to another take place in the For loop.